# Is this a valid visualization of the "git stash" operation?

Tags: git, visualization, git-stash

I can not find a good visualization of the `git stash` operation. So I created my own based on some rare comments on the internet.

[image]

This this visualization correct?

Edit note: I need to change the color of `stash@{0}` because it's no branch.

Where are stashes stored in my `.git` directory? I think it's a reference and stored in `refs`, right?

---

Legend:

- C1, C2 - commits
- Idx - Index
- WD - working directory
- dashed line and dashed borders => free for garbage collection

---

**Reworked Image**

[image]

Comment: I would add a new arrow, perhaps with a dotted stem, from `WD` to `test` and from `Idx` to `Idx` and a legend entry saying that represents applying those changes. I don't know if you want to attempt representing the merges (essentially a pair of cherry-picks) stash does when you pop/apply/branch onto a different base, but that usage gets very handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "before `git stash`" and "after `git stash`" graphs are essentially correct (there are two new commits, not on any branch, pointed-to by `refs/stash` aka `stash@{0}`).  What's missing from this diagram is that the index and work-tree themselves are reset, in the same way `git reset --hard` does it—in fact, *using* `git reset --hard`—after `git stash`.

The "after `git stash branch`" graph is [edit to match new diagram]
 much harder to draw, though: `git stash branch` uses the `idx` and `wd` commits to restore the state of the index and work-tree, and then *drops them entirely* from `refs/stash`.  Those two commits now have no name at all and are therefore eligible for garbage collection (`git gc` may now remove them as soon as they expire, in terms of "prune time", based on `gc.pruneExpire` in your configuration).  The new branch name `test` points to the parent commit to which `idx` and `WD` pointed, back when `idx` and `WD` were still guaranteed to exist.

Making a new commit immediately at this point (`git stash branch <name> && git commit`) will make a new commit from the restored index, as in the updated drawing.

> Where are stashes stored in my .git directory?

The commits themselves are commits, and hence are stored like any other commit, in `.git/objects/` (as loose or packed objects).

> I think it's a reference and stored in refs, right?

Yes, `refs/stash` is a reference.  The `git stash` code uses (or abuses?) the reflog entries for `refs/stash` to manage the "stash stack", so both the hash ID in `refs/stash` itself, and all those in any `refs/stash` reflog entries, matter: they keep the `WD` commit alive, by pointing directly to it, and hence also keep the `idx` commit (the `^2` or second parent of `WD`) alive (since it is reachable through the `WD` commit).

Comment: So `git stash branch` is a short form of `git checkout -b test; git stash apply; git stash drop; git commit -a -m "foo bar"`?

Comment: It's: `git checkout -b <branchname> <stash_selector>^1 && git stash apply --index <stash_selector> && git stash drop <stash_selector>`. The stash is applied with `--index` so as to keep `idx` and `WD` apart, applying the `idx` commit exclusively to the index.There is no final `git commit` step.

Comment: Please see my updated question with a reworked drawing. Is it now OK?

Comment: @Paebbels Well, no: After `git stash branch`, the state is exactly the same as before the corresponding `git stash`, except for the fact that you are now on a new branch called `test` which points directly at the commit `C2`. The weakness of your drawing is, that you do not show the state of the index and currently checked out working tree.

Comment: @cmaster Oh, you are right. Now I got it, torek has no `git commit` in his list of command, which I always assumed. I know that the image has a weakness regarding staging area, but don't want to make it overly complicated.

Comment: Right: add a `git commit` step after `git stash branch` and Git will write the index as a new commit. Then your latest graph will be more or less accurate, though we cannot see that the work-tree contents are restored.