# what does the incorrect syntax of `git stash show -p @{0}` show (instead of using the correct `stash@{0}`)

Tags: git, bash

I was playing around with stashes in git and ran into some seemingly strange behavior.

After creating a number of stashes, I wanted to see what was in them.  I ran `git stash show -p` and it showed me a diff of the last stash as one would expect.  I then wanted to confirm that index 0 referred to the most recent stash, so I (incorrectly) ran `git stash show -p @{0}`.  This gave me the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Fair enough.  But what's weird was that it then gave me a diff of a bunch of changes that I didn't recognize and that didn't exist in any of my stashes.

What was `@{0}` referring to in this context and where was that diff coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on [kostix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46731359/1256452), the `git stash` code uses the following principles:

- "The" stash (the default one) is identified by the name `refs/stash`, so that `stash@{number}` is a reflog entry for this reference.
- Each stash is in practice made up of two (or sometimes three) commits, as shown in the diagram in [Is this a valid visualization of the "git stash" operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46575029/1256452)  The `stash` reference points to the working-directory or work-tree commit, which has two (or three if the third commit is present) parent commits.  This means that if the work-tree commit is treated as if it were a regular commit made by regular Git commands, it would simply be a merge commit.  (Actually treating it as an ordinary merge can produce peculiar effects, so it's best to use the `git stash` command to work with it.)

This second point—which is an implementation detail—nonetheless affects the `git stash` code quite strongly.  In particular, `git stash` will believe that *any* commit *is* a valid stash if and only if it is a merge commit.  It does not actually require that the commit be named via `refs/stash` or one of the corresponding reflog entries.

If you write `stash@{1}`, the rules as outlined in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) will normally find `refs/stash` and extract the 1-th reflog entry (i.e., the first one, not counting the `stash@{0}` entry, which technically isn't a reflog entry at all: Git just retrieves the value of the reference itself, instead of an entry from the reflog).

Assuming `stash@{1}` exists, this will name one of your stash work-tree commits, which will be a merge commit.  The `git stash` code verifies that the commit you have named is "stash-like", i.e., has the prescribed form.

But this also means that if you run some of the `git stash` sub-commands (such as `show` or `apply`) using a hash ID, or a branch name, or any other name acceptable to the revision parsing code—*including* an ordinary reflog-like reference like `@{0}`, which means "the value extracted from HEAD"—the stash code will attempt to do its thing with that commit.

If that commit passes the "is stash-like" test, the stash code will treat it *as if it were* a stash.  Since the "is stash-like" test is basically "is a merge commit", what happens with `git stash show @{0}` or `git stash show HEAD` is that if the current commit is a merge, `git stash show` tends to show part of it (technically it simply diffs `HEAD^1` against `HEAD`).  If it's *not* a merge commit, `git stash show` should complain and quit:

```
'HEAD' is not a stash-like commit
```

but older versions of Git are not always as clever.  If your Git is truly ancient, it may attempt to show some existing stash, passing the extra arguments on to `git diff` which will complain about them.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`gitrevisions(7)` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)
(you can run `git help revisions`):

> `@{<n>}`, e.g. `@{1}`
>
> You can use the `@` construct with an empty ref part to get at a reflog entry of the current branch.For example, if you are on branch `blabla` then `@{1}` means the same as `blabla@{1}`.

Comment: `@{0}` is invalid in this case.

Comment: @ElpieKay that's what the OP's problem was about, no?